# Listen to only window's width change (not height)

Tags: javascript, window, resize, width

I'm aware of

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {}
```

and

```
window.onresize = function(event) {}
```

But is there a way to listen to WIDTH only ?

I would like the simplest way to trigg an event when ONLY the window's width is changing.

To give some context, actually I'm using

```
window.onresize = function(event) {}
```

and I'm trying to prevent the function to trig when you scroll down in iOs Safari.

Thanks to who can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this behavior by storing the last width in a variable. and then compare the last width with the current width if they are not equal then do whatever you want and then update the last width.

```js
let lastWidth = window.innerWidth

window.onresize = function(event) {
    if (window.innerWidth !== lastWidth) {
        // your code
        
        // update the last width
        lastWidth = window.innerWidth
    }
}
```